# How can I sample from a copula with a given correlation in python?

Tags: python, sampling, copula

How can I sample from a normal copula with a given correlation in python?

I know how to sample from a multivariate normal distribution with a given covariance matrix using numpy and scipy, but I don't know how to generate and sample from a copula with a given correlation.

Comment: look up the Cholesky inversion method. extending it to copulas just needs the usual uniform marginal transformations of copulas

Comment: Note that questions about code are off topic. If you need guidance on that, you'll need to ask on stackoverflow

Comment: I actually think there’s a statistics question hidden in here, chiefly the relationship between the parameters of a Gaussian copula and correlation between the marginal distributions.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually straight forward then:

If you have simulated some random variables $(X_1,X_2)$ which are normally distributed with $\sigma_1=\sigma_2=1$ and correlation $\rho$ then $(F(X_1),F(X_2))$ are observations from the gauss copula. $F(\cdot)$ is this case the univariate standard normal cdf.